# AsyncTask in android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to execute some code parallel with threads using async task.
But for some reason in android 4.2.2 doesn't work.

I have this code which is in main class:

```
new XmlDownloader();

task=new SendTask().execute("");
```

and the following classes:

```
 private class SendTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...strings){

               while(true){                               

                    Log.w("outside", "hello");  
             }            
          }

            return strings[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String country){


        }
     }
```

and

```
    public class XmlDownloader extends Activity {


public XmlDownloader(int pos) {


    DownloaderTask task = new DownloaderTask();

    task.execute("");
}


private String downloadXml(String s,int pos1) {

    return null;
}


private class DownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public DownloaderTask() {

    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         while(true){
             Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd");   
             if(isCancelled())
                 return null;
         };


         return null;

    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(String bitmap) {


    }
}
 }
```

In android 2.3.3 the logcat shows this sequence

```
 Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd");   
 Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd");   
 Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd");       
 Log.w("outside", "hello");
 Log.w("outside", "hello");
 Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd");
```

but in android 4.2.2 only shows

```
   Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd"); 
   Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd"); 
   Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd"); 
   Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd"); 
   Log.w("down", "asdasdasssasdasdasdasd");
```

Any ideas why threads don't work?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: The sequence is wrong.Its like a serial execution and  i want a parallel execution.Which is strange because async creates threads. Like i said in 2.3.3 works fine

Comment: Look at my answer, I edited it and you can find the answer to why it's happening...try starting the second thread first and you'll see printed only the other string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `AsyncTask` may not give you the true parallelism that you need. Across different versions of Android, the number of `AsyncTask`s that can run simultaneously has been changed from 1 to 5 and then back to 1 (If I'm not wrong).

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commits/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M

`AsyncTask`s are backed by a `ThreadPool` over which you have no control. If `AsyncTask` doesn't fit your needs, is to use Services or `Loopers` or build your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`. AsyncTask is not designed to loop idefinitely, that is to be a server or a service.

So what is happening is that in your Android version only the first enqueued thread from the pool is executed and since it doesn't terminate (they will be run sequentially), the second one never starts.

Comment: So what are you suggesting exactly to do in order to make this work?

Comment: It depends on what you want do to...for that example to work simply use two Threads. If you need to post on the UI, pass an Handler to the threads. ThreadPoolExecutor is used to have control on how many threads can run concurrently and on the max number of Thread that can be instantiated. As I said, it is based on your needs.

Comment: There is also the method AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(...) where you can specify your own Executor with more than one thread.

Comment: Sure it is a viable solution, but it requires Api level 11, and according to this diagram: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html you will be targeting the 60% of the current devices. Also they rollbacked to a sequential executor in order to avoid people introducing hard-to-find bugs in the code.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the way AsyncTasks have evolved since their conception in API 3. In `API 3`, AsyncTasks(plural) were executed serially. This was changed to a pool of threads, allowing multiple AsyncTasks to run in parallel (`API 4(DONUT)`). But, starting `HONEYCOMB(API 11)`, AsyncTasks are back to being executed serially.

Looking at the output you have provided, both `SendTask` & `DownloaderTask` execute in parallel in case of `2.3.3` which is > DONUT and < HONEYCOMB. But, in case of `4.2.2`, serial execution of AsyncTasks takes place. Since `DownloaderTask` is executed first, SendTask waits for it to finish execution(which won't happen thanks to while(true)) --> hence, no output.

Since API 11, you have a choice over whether your AsyncTasks run serially or in parallel. For serial execution, use `execute(Params... params)`. For parallel execution, look into `executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params)`.